# Storing camera captured image in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am Capturing Photo with camera,Stored temporarily on "ImageView" and then Storing it in Database by clicking Save button on Activity. But Saving an Image in Database is not Working. Please resolve the Problem in Code.

```
   Main File:
     <!-- language: java -->   

   package com.example.expnewbutton;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.provider.MediaStore;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.Toast;
   public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
private Uri fileUri;
    Bitmap img;
    databasehelper helper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

public void cammethod(View w){ 

    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        boolean doesHaveCamera = packageManager
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);

        if (doesHaveCamera) {
            // start the image capture Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // Get our fileURI
            //fileUri = getOutputMediaFile();

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "There was an error with the camera.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent)

{
    if (requestCode == 100) 
     {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            if (intent == null) 
            {
                // The picture was taken but not returned
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "The picture was taken and is located here: "
                                + fileUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
            else 
            {
                // The picture was returned
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                img=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");    
                ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)           findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) extras.get("data"));
            }
        }
    }
}

public void insertimg(View w)
{ 
    long a=0;
    try{
    helper.insert(img);

    if(a>=1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),a+ "Record Successfully Saved",   30).show();
    }

    else{

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Not Saved", 30).show();

    }}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "there is error",5).show();
    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}

   DataBase File:
   <!-- language: java -->

           package com.example.expnewbutton;
           import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
           import android.content.ContentValues;
           import android.content.Context;
           import android.database.Cursor;
          import android.database.SQLException;
          import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
          import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
          import android.graphics.Bitmap;
         import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
         import android.util.Log;


        public class databasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    final static String databasename="Imagedb";
    final static int databaseversion=1;

        public databasehelper(Context ctx){
      super(ctx,databasename,null,databaseversion);

    }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{

         Log.d("tag4545","database");   
      db.execSQL("create table mypic(pic BLOB)");

    }
    catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("drop table if Exists mypic");

    onCreate(db);

       }

        public long insert(Bitmap img ) {

    SQLiteDatabase base=getWritableDatabase();
    byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img); // this is a function
       ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
      value.put("pic",data);

       long a= base.insert("mypic", null, value);  

      return a; 
       }

      public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) 
    {
      ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
      return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
      }


    XML file is
  <!-- language: xml -->

     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
     android:background="@drawable/gb2"
 >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Cam"

    android:onClick="cammethod" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="insertimg"
    android:text="Save" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't captured more problems on your code and there is no any log available.

I fond only twos. :)

1. You forgot to initialize database class..

   ```
   helper.insert(img);
   ```

   So before using above code line just initialize database class in `onCreate()` of Activity. something like,

   ```
   databasehelper helper = new databasehelper(this);
   ```
2. Where is the value of `a` will be changed?

   So it should be like,

   ```
   long a=0;
   try{
   a = helper.insert(img);
   ```

Anyway these two can help you to move ahead.

Comment: Hey Man,I am newbie to programming and Its such silly and Damn bad Mistakes. Really Thank you. But Can you tell me Why is it necessary to intialize the class before using that particular code "helper.insert(img)".

Comment: @Avin, because this method is not static, you need an instance of the object to run this method on it. this is the reason you need to initialize the class before using it's method.

Comment: @Emil, What do you mean "I need an instance of the object". Do you mean i need an reference to the object or something ??

Comment: By this i mean that you need to perform this line: databasehelper helper = new databasehelper(this);